# ArcGIS contours creation using ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a raster on ArcGIS and I want to add some contours. I use the ArcPy library to do that. This is the raster (part of a country) and the contours:

[image]

This is the raster with the contours:

[image]

and this is the same image, zoomed:

[image]

I am trying to do the same like the image below:

[image]

But the contours that are created are not in the shape I imagined. I just have a raster with different values and I want to add contours like in the last image.

Is there any tool that I can do that? In my script I use the simple arcpy.sa.Contour command. I just want to add contours of ground acceleration around an epicenter.

Comment: Choose a contour interval that results in fewer contours.  Use the Smooth Line tool (sum experimentation with parameters required) to reduce the right angles of your contours.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/smooth-line.htm

Comment: You might also want to double check if your contours are in the units you expect them to be in.